# I am using a phonenumbers module for validating phone numbers. It works well,however I just need the National number as output

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, parsing, phone-number

```
import phonenumbers
ph_no = "918332 88 1992"
print(phonenumbers.parse(ph_no, "IN"))
```

Output:

```
Country Code: 91 National Number: 8332881992
```

Desired Output:

`8332881992`

I just need the phonenumber to return. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You need the `national_number` attribute of the parsed phone number. [Docs can be found here](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers).

```
import phonenumbers
ph_no = "918332 88 1992"
p = phonenumbers.parse(ph_no, "IN")
print(p.national_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the [**`.national_number`** attribute [GitHub]](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/release-5.5b1/python/phonenumbers/phonenumber.py#L57) of the parsed phone number:

```
import phonenumbers

ph_no = "918332 88 1992"

print(phonenumbers.parse(ph_no, "IN").national_number)
```